# Execute AWS ECS run-task with network configuration overrides

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I'm running a task in AWS ECS using the CLI command [run-task](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html).

I'm successfully running a task as follows:

```
aws ecs run-task --cluster ${stackName}-cluster \
                 --task-definition ${stackName}-${tag} \
                 --launch-type="FARGATE" \
                 --network-configuration '{ "awsvpcConfiguration": { "assignPublicIp":"DISABLED", "securityGroups": ["sg-......"], "subnets": ["subnet-.....","subnet-.....","subnet-......"]}}' \
                 --count 1 \
                 --profile ${profile} \
                 --overrides file://overrides.json
```

They way I understand it, if you're using FARGATE you must to have `NetworkMode: awsvpc` in your TaskDefinition, and you need to specify the awsvpcConfiguration every time you run a task. This is all fine.

However, to make the above invocation tidier, is there a way to pass the --networkConfiguration above as an override. The documentation says you can pass environment variables, but it's not clear if this includes network.

I would be very grateful to anybody who could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that. [Here's the full list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskOverride.html) of things you can specify in ECS Task Overrides. Network configuration is not in that list.

> The documentation says you can pass environment variables, but it's not clear if this includes network.

The network configuration is not an environment variable.

---

If you just want to be able to simplify the the command line by passing in more arguments from a file, you can use the `--cli-input-json`
or `--cli-input-yaml` [arguments](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Tested passing `--cli-input-json file://network.json` and it works as expected.